# How to remove everything after a word in apache url with rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I need some help with regex and an Apache rewrite, I still have yet to comprehend regex patterns, I see a lot of previous questions on doing something similar in php (which I know a lot about), but I can't seem to convert it to a rewrite rule.

I used to use Smugmug for my photography website, then I just made my own, Smugmug added some random letters at the end of each url to make it more `"private"`, like this `"Blog/Jenny-Easter-Pictures/i-nbRcmgv"`

I kept the same folder structure, except the random characters, and because of that, Google, and possibly my old old clients are getting a not found error since its looking for a `"i-nbRcmgv"` folder

I want apache to remove everything after (and including) the `"/i-"` in the url, needs to include the slash, in case I ever have a folder name that does have an i- in it of course.

Sounds like it might be easy, but like I said, regex baffles me, and I don't use it enough to learn it all AND remember it for the next time ha.

I already have something like this in my conf, so I have a general idea on what to do, but I copied it from someone else's answered question on this site.

```
RewriteRule ^/downloads/(.*)/$ /download.php?DIR=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/i-.*  $1  [QSD]
```

Remove [QSD] if you want to preserve the query part after the "?" in the url (eg `Blog/Jenny-Easter-Pictures/i-nbRcmg?a=b` should become `Blog/Jenny-Easter-Pictures?a=b`)

Comment: worked great thanks, made it an R=301 flag for Google to stop going to the old one